# Does NTIME($n^\alpha$) $\subset$ EXPTIME imply NP $\subset$ EXPTIME?

Tags: time-complexity, np

I think I'm able to prove NTIME($n^\alpha$) $\subset$ EXPTIME for arbitrary $\alpha$.

- Is this a new result?
- If it was, would there be a way to deduce NP $\subset$ EXPTIME from it?

Comment: It’s knows that $\mathsf{NTIME}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(2^{f(n)})$, and this implies that $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{EXPTIME}$.

Comment: With "$\subset$" do you mean a *proper* inclusion or is equality allowed? (In the latter case, see Yuval Filmus' comment.)

Comment: Assuming strict inclusion, I'd lean towards "no" for the second question. From $A \subset X$ and $B \subset X$ we can only conclude the loose inclusion $A \cup B \subseteq X$, and not the stricter $A \cup B \subset X$, in general.

Comment: Yes, I meant proper inclusion.

Comment: $\subset$ is ambiguous: it's better to use $\subseteq$ for the "maybe equal" version and $\subsetneq$ (`\subsetneq`) for the "definitely not equal" version.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reflection this is an easy consequence of the Time Hierarchy Theorem.

- NTIME$(n^\alpha) \subseteq$ TIME$\left(2^{n^\alpha}\right)$ by brute force
- TIME$\left(2^{n^\alpha}\right) \subset$ TIME$\left(2^{n^{2\alpha}}\right)$ by the Time Hierarchy Theorem
- TIME$\left(2^{n^{2\alpha}}\right) \subseteq$ EXPTIME obviously

So there's nothing new here.

Answer (score 1):

As you've [already shown](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/102637/9550), $\mathrm{NTIME}[n^\alpha]\subsetneq\mathrm{EXPTIME}$ isn't new, as it follows easily from the time hierarchy theorem.

Furthermore, the fact that, for some class $X$, $\mathrm{NTIME}[n^\alpha]\subsetneq X$ for all $\alpha$ doesn't imply that $\mathrm{NP}\subsetneq X$. For example, the time hierarchy theorem tells us $\mathrm{NTIME}[n^\alpha]\subsetneq\mathrm{NP}$ for all $\alpha$ but that certainly doesn't imply that $\mathrm{NP}\subsetneq\mathrm{NP}\,$!